# Swift closure calling async process concatenates return value repeatedly

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures

I have a process that loops through a collection of items. For each item, it performs an async call that passes in an array that is populated by the child async call. The array that is returned should have values related to each item in the collection. What is happening is that the array is ultimately populated with duplicates, like this:
([values for collection 1], [values for collection1] [values for collection 2], [values for collection1] [values for collection 2], [values for collection 3])

Pretty confusing to explain. In the real world, this is taking a collection of podcasts, and for each podcast getting all episodes, and for each episode checking if it is after a certain date and then acting on it.

Here is the code:

```
for collection in podcastCollections {
           //loop through all episodes for collection
          dispatchGroup.enter()
            let _ = localNetworkLookup.getEpisodesFromFeedURL(urlParam: collection.feedUrl) { (returnedItems)  in
               //bug is that returnedItems is just appended to in each call, it does not start fresh for each collection
               for item in returnedItems {
                   if item.feedPubDate! >= collection.dateLastRefresh! {
                          newEpisode = PodcastEpisode(feedTitle: item.feedTitle!, feedLink: "", feedContent: item.feedContent!)                       
                         //this is the issue here- it loads the same episodes repeatedly, because they stick around in returnedItems
                         //but I expect returnedItems to only have items for the collection that is currently in the loop
                         triageEpisodes.append(newEpisode!)
                         print ("added \(newEpisode!.feedTitle)")
                   }//if  pub date
                 }//for items
              }//localNetworkLookup.getEpisodesFromFeedURL
           dispatchGroup.leave()
        }//for collection
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {

            print (triageEpisodes.count)


        }//dispatch group notify
```

I have worked with closures and async stuff before, but have never dealt with looping like this. Thanks in advance for any help, I'm totally stumped.

My question is-how can I have the output reflect the episodes for each podcast with no duplicates. Currently every loop includes the contents of the previous network call. The current output looks like this:

added #1743: Sherman LeTank
added #1742: The Nobel Grease Prize

**And now it repeats ***

added #1743: Sherman LeTank
added #1742: The Nobel Grease Prize
added A Visit to Barbra's Place
added Bernie Sanders Thinks Democrats Are Still Way Off-Course

**And now it repeats ***

added #1743: Sherman LeTank
added #1742: The Nobel Grease Prize
added A Visit to Barbra's Place
added Bernie Sanders Thinks Democrats Are Still Way Off-Course
added #167 - Death By Design
added #166 - Geez. I Don't Know
added #CLXV - Elevated Permissions
added #164 - Running Down A Dream
added #1743: Sherman LeTank
added #1742: The Nobel Grease Prize
added A Visit to Barbra's Place
added Bernie Sanders Thinks Democrats Are Still Way Off-Course
added #167 - Death By Design
added #166 - Geez. I Don't Know
added #CLXV - Elevated Permissions
added #164 - Running Down A Dream
added Putting Dr. Seuss on the Couch

**EDIT**
*So it turns out the reason this is happening is because the closure stays in scope for the entire loop cycle. That means that the variables the closure uses also stay in scope, so there is no way to isolate the values returned in any particular call from inside the loop. My fix is to create a new array outside of the loop, and in ever iteration of the loop set the new array to the array returned by the closure. The last run of the loop will end up with a fully populated array. But there is no way to do any processing with the closure results inside the loop.*

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: your `dispatchGroup.leave()` should be inside the completion block of `getEpisodesFromFeedURL` to begin with.

Comment: Same issue no matter how I set up the dispatch group. The issue seems to be that the returnedItems array is reused and appended to on each call, rather than just containing items for the collection currently in the loop.